# Sort sequence by two column

Tags: sql, sorting, seq

Current List

```
Item# |  To      |  From    |
A100  |  000000  |  803441  |
A200  |  803441  |  000000  |
A300  |  000000  |  542032  |
A400  |  181061  |  000000  |
A500  |  000000  |  181061  |
A600  |  542032  |  000000  |
```

Correct Sorted List * Im not exactly sure if this is 100% right outcome

```
Item# |  To      |  From    |
A100  |  000000  |  803441  |
A200  |  803441  |  000000  |
A500  |  000000  |  181061  |
A400  |  181061  |  000000  |
A300  |  000000  |  542032  |
A600  |  542032  |  000000  |
```

First it needs to sort by Item#, but second part Im not sure how to explain, Basically a item needs to be taken out (#:00000) before you can put a new item back in

Having trouble thinking, perhaps my fever is in the way, but I was thinking if it has to do with merging the #?

Also, I need this query work only for sql 2008, Thanks!

Comment: Why are the rows with `181061` before `542032`, but after `803441`?

Comment: does not matter, perhaps respective item# should be ordered first

Comment: I think I understood your requirement. By SQL 2008, do you mean Microsoft SQL Server 2008, or the SQL:2008 ANSI standard?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 1):

You might try this:

```
order by
   CASE WHEN to > from THEN to ELSE from END
  ,to
```

If you want to order by the lowest Item# first youz can apply a *Windowed Aggregate*:

```
SELECT *

FROM tab
ORDER BY 
   Min(Item#) 
   Over (PARTITION BY CASE WHEN to > from THEN to ELSE from END)
  ,to
```